# Couldn't match type Data.Enumerator.Internal.Iteratee with IO

Tags: haskell, yesod

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.Enumerator.List (consume)

data App = App
mkYesod "App" [parseRoutesNoCheck|
/*Texts WikR GET --PathMultiPiece handler for all combinations
/ WikiR POST
|]
instance Yesod App

getWikR :: [Text] -> Handler Text
getWikR parts = return "" --defaultLayout [whamlet||]

postWikiR = do
    bss <- lift consume
    return $ RepJson $ toContent $ L.fromChunks bss

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

gives the error,

```
yesod/hw.hs:14:1:
    Couldn't match type ‘Data.Enumerator.Internal.Iteratee
                           Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString m0’
                  with ‘IO’
    Expected type: HandlerT App IO RepJson
      Actual type: HandlerT
                     App
                     (Data.Enumerator.Internal.Iteratee
                        Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString m0)
                     RepJson
    In the first argument of ‘yesodRunner’, namely ‘postWikiR’
    In the expression:
      yesodRunner postWikiR env3739_adGV (Just WikiR) req3739_adGW
```

The error line @ln-num#14 is `mkYesod "App" [parseRoutesNoCheck|`

I am sure, the error is to do with `postWikiR#return $ RepJson $ toContent $ L.fromChunks bss`. But not sure, how to fix?

[Reference-1](https://github.com/snoyberg/haskell-web-rosetta/blob/master/json-request/yesod.hs)

Comment: That Rosetta project is out of date. I'd recommend reading content on yesodweb.com instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are trying to run old code that does not work with current Yesod.

You can get this to compile and run (ghc-7.10.1, yesod-1.4.1.5) with

```
import Data.Enumerator (run_)
...
bss <- run_ consume
```

but I'm not sure what you want it to do.  As is, it will return an empty list.